# Edge of cube poking out

Tags: vertices

Hello I am new to blender and as I was moving the skeleton of a cube I started having this issue where the edge pokes out and doesnt stick to the line of the vertice I make for it when I press z to see just the skeleton it looks like theres a transparent edge poking out is there a fix for this? (Sorry if this sounds confusing just new)

[image]

[image: Image of poking edge]

Comment: Could you share your file with me?  You can use this link:https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Heres the file 

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=EDv6AZQr" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/EDv6AZQr/)

Comment: just to be clear, these are the edges you want to get rid of right? :https://imgur.com/lMfONO2

Comment: Yes those are the edges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to get ride of these edges is simply delete them, and then refill the empty spaces.  Just follow along with the images below:

step 1: in edit mode, select all undesired edges
[image]
Step 2: press the "x" key, then click on "edges"
[image]
Step 3: your shape should look like this after steps 1 & 2
[image]
Step 4: Select all the edges on one side around the spot with a hole
[image]
Step 5:  with the edges around one of the holes selected, press the "f" key on your keyboard.  After that, it should fill in the hole, like in the image below:
[image]
Step 6:  Repeat steps 4 & 5 on the other 3 holes.  After that.  You should have a mesh that looks something like this:
[image]
hope this helped!  If you encounter further problems, let me know :)

(PS, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: no problem.  happy I helped : )